# 400 Bad Request on application running Django Backend

Tags: django, favicon, http-status-code-400

I am trying to run an application that uses a Django backend/api and an React frontend. The frontend runs fine.

I'm starting the backend by running the following:

`./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8003`

And it starts without issues. I then start the frontend with

`npm run build`

When I go to the IP where I think my app is running,

`123.123.12.123:8003`

I see a 400 (Bad Request) error.

The following errors show up in my terminal:

`[14/May/2019 17:45:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 26
[14/May/2019 17:45:43] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 26`

every time I refresh the page.

I'm new to Django so I'm hoping there is something simple that I am missing. From googling the error, I saw a lot of people saying that adding some html like `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>`. There is no html in my django backend so I have nowhere to put this.

Comment: set `ALLOWED_HOSTS=[*]` in `settings.py`

Comment: `npm run build` does not start front app `npm run dev` does. Why are you concerned about favicon if previous GET of the root page fails with similar error? Read the logs.

Answer (score 0):

as @hari mentioned in the response comment to @ellen the 400 error is most commonly related to a misconfiguration of the  `ALLOWED_HOSTS` variable inside the `settings.py` file of the Django project, but it might not always be the case.

Let's dive into the issue!

If you look at the Django documentation for the [Bad Request View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/views/#http-bad-request-view) you can see that this page is shown as a `default view` whenever there is a [Suspicious Operation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.SuspiciousOperation); which in turn is defined as an exception:

> The SuspiciousOperation exception is raised when a user has performed an operation that should be considered suspicious from a security perspective, such as tampering with a session cookie.

In there you can see a list of possible suspicious operations you can check in your `setings.py` file or in your Django or server configurations.

In many cases -and especially if you are new to Django and have not tampered with many things- the applicable solution is to look if you have `DEBUG` disabled and then review the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` variable to check if your host is being allowed or change the `DEBUG` variable back to true (only if you are still in dev). So:

- Go to the `<project_folde>/setting.py` file
- Change `DEBUG` to `True` if you are still on `dev`
- Add your host to the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` configuration

In my case, as I'm on PROD I had to do this:

```py
DEBUG = Fasle

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
  'mybeautifulpage.org',
  'localhost',
  '127.0.0.1'
]
```

And it started working like a charm.